# Schedule code execution in the future

Tags: android, events, handler

I wonder what the best way is to implement this behavior:

I have an event X with an id that happens from time to time.
If the event with a certain id happened, I want to execute some code after 25 seconds, except if X with the same id happens again, in that case I want it to be postponed again with 25 seconds.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: I'd personally prefer a `Handler`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a simple handler to delay running something for 25 seconds.  It's up to you to figure out how to filter on some ID.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

   public void myEvent() {

      // Remove any callback that may be registered, this will reset it if called before
      handler.removeCallbacks(runMe);
      // Execute the runnable in 25 seconds
      handler.postDelayed(runMe, 25000);
   }
   Runnable runMe = new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
         // This will run after the postDelayed expires in 25 seconds
         Log.d("TAG", "Run me at some time");
      }
   };
```